# Incomplete HTML after Executing `document.write()`

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, overwrite, document.write

After executing `document.write()`, Google Chrome shows me that the HTML codes is changed from **Code A** to **Code B**. It seems that `document.write()` overwrite the entire page. If yes, how to append the script tag inside head tag?

**Code A : Before Executing `document.write()`**

```
<!--DOCTYE html-->
<html>
<head>
    <script src=".\js\main_CasCode.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="main()">
    <p>hi</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**Code B : After Executing `document.write()`**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
</html>
```

**JavaScript in File `.\js\main_CasCode.js`**

```
function main() {
    //console.log = function() {};
    loadjQuery();
    //waitjQueryLoaded_and_start();
}

function loadjQuery() {
    console.log("Loading jQuery...");
    var s = '<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>';
    document.write(s);  //<----Problem Here
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `document.write` erases and rewrites the document when the document has already finished rendering (like after `onload`). It only appears to append when called during the rendering of the page.

A better way to do this is to dynamically create a script element, add it to the page, and add an `src` which triggers the loading mechanism.

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
script.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js';
```

In other news, why are you loading jQuery dynamically when you have control of the page? Why not add it directly as a `<script>` on the HTML?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you want to be using document.write at all. You can use the following. Make a script element, and append it to the head element

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]
var s = document.createElement('script')
s.src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"
head.appendChild(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

document.write overwrites the whole DOM

You can create a function

```
function loadjQuery() {
    console.log("Loading jQuery...");
    var scrpt = document.createElement('script');
    scrpt.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js';
    document.head.appendChild(scrpt);  
}
```